# How to view a plot in Google Cloud VM (SSH)

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to run a image classification on Google Cloud Engine VM (via SSH login) model and trying to plot a graph for accuracy and loss. Model is running fine but getting error for graph plot. Below is code and error message.

Can anyone have idea how to fix this error in SSH Virtual Machine?

Tried 'tkagg' for matplotlib backend, but still getting the error.

Graph Code

```
import matplotlib  matplotlib.use('tkagg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

plot the training loss and accuracy

```
fig = plt.figure() plt.style.use("ggplot") plt.plot(np.arange(0, 10),
    H.history["loss"], label="train_loss") plt.plot(np.arange(0, 10), 
    H.history["val_loss"], label="val_loss") plt.plot(np.arange(0, 10),
    H.history["acc"], label="train_acc") plt.plot(np.arange(0, 10),
    H.history["val_acc"], label="val_acc") plt.title("Training Loss and Accuracy") 
    plt.xlabel("Epoch #") 
    plt.ylabel("Loss/Accuracy") 
    plt.legend() 
    plt.savefig('without_aug.png', dpi = fig.dpi, bbox_inches = 'tight')
```

Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "minivggnet_flowers17.py", line 73, in 
>       fig = plt.figure()
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 533, in figure
>       **kwargs)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 161, in new_figure_manager
>       return cls.new_figure_manager_given_figure(num, fig)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/_backend_tk.py", line 1046, in new_figure_manager_given_figure
>       window = Tk.Tk(className="matplotlib")
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1823, in **init**
>       self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
>   _tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable

Can anyone have idea how to fix this error in SSH Virtual Machine?

Comment: Welcome to SO; please do spend a minute to see how to properly format your code blocks (done it for you this time. Also, question has nothing to do with `deep-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: Thank you @desertnaut. Will keep the code blocks properly from next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jupiter lab for visualization and running codes line by line.In the cloud VM you need to install jupyter lab using pip - **pip install jupyterlab** and then start the jupyter lab server by typing this command in terminal -

**jupyter lab --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=9090**
use the link provided by the output of this command to paste it on your web browser to open jupyter notebook. here you can run matplotlib imshow function for visualization.

**Note :-** ***port no*** can be anything but must be open to access from over the internet. you need to check google cloud VM network setting to add port no for global users or make it public.

Answer (score 0):

As the marked answer said, use jupyter notebook. But you may run into an issue as I did.
The `jupyter lab` command didn't exist, if you run into this problem, just install jupyter with pip and run `~/.local/bin/jupyter lab --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=9090`

Comment: Did the command not exist because of a version number difference? It would be helpful to elucidate that in the Answer.

Comment: @ryanwebjackson I dont know what it was, but I just put this out there to help those whom faced this issue.